# Print 2D array to console in board format

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to print my 2D array to the console as if the array were co-ordinates on a chess board for example, my code looks like this:

```
 public Piece[][] getBoardView() throws NoBoardDefinedException
{
     System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(board));
     return board;
}
```

This currently prints the 2D array in one straight line across the console, can anyone suggest a way to change this into a board style format?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    for (Piece[] row : board)
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
```

Answer (score 0):

if this is the case then you would get likewise,

```
int chessboard [][] = {
                                  {1,2,3},
                                  {4,5,6},
                                  {7,8,9}
                                   };

        for(int i = 0; i < chessboard.length ; i ++){

            System.out.println();
            for(int j = 0 ; j < chessboard[i].length ; j++){
                System.out.print(" | " + chessboard[i][j]  );
            }
            System.out.print(" |");
            System.out.println();
        }
```

OUT PUT :

```
 | 1 | 2 | 3 |

 | 4 | 5 | 6 |

 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
```